# Issues with returning an object from an angularjs promise

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am basically trying to **retrieve the user's current position** using the geolocation api and then pass the coordinates as parameters to an angularjs ajax call and **return a custom "address" object** as follows:

from the used module:

```
angular.module('geolocationModule', ['ng'])
.factory('geolocationService', ['$http', function geolocationService($http) {
    return {
        geolocationPosition : function(){
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    return $http.post('/bignibou/geolocation/approximateReverse/', {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude})
                    .then(function(formattedAddress){
                        var address = {};
                        address.formattedAddress = formattedAddress;
                        return address;
                    },
                    function(data, status, headers, config){
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(status);
                    });
                }, errorFn, {
                    timeout : 10000
                });
            }
        }
    };  
}]);
```

from calling module:

```
angular.module('searchEngineModule', ['ng', 'geolocationModule'])
.controller('geolocationCtrl', [ '$scope', 'geolocationService', function geolocationCtrl($scope, geolocationService) {
        $scope.init = function(){
            var geolocationAddress ={};
            geolocationAddress = geolocationService.geolocationPosition();
            console.log(geolocationAddress);
        };
}]);
```

For some reason, **my geolocationAddress object is always undefined**...

Can anyone please help?

**edit 1**:

If I use the following async code:

```
var geolocationAddress ={};
geolocationService.geolocationPosition().then(function(data) {
     geolocationAddress = data;
});
console.log(geolocationAddress);
```

Here is what I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
    at Object.$scope.init (http://localhost:8080/bignibou/js/custom/searchEngine.js:5:45)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js:6541:19
    at Object.Scope.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js:8218:28)
    at pre (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js:13636:15)
    at nodeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js:4568:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js:4191:15)
    at publicLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js:4096:30)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js:1042:27
    at Object.Scope.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js:8218:28)
    at Object.Scope.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js:8298:23) <body ng-app="searchEngineModule" ng-controller="geolocationCtrl" ng-init="init()" style="" class="ng-scope">
```

**edit 2**: Taking into account Chandermani's comments and updating to the following sorted the issue:

```
angular.module('geolocationModule', ['ng'])
.factory('geolocationService', ['$http', '$q', '$rootScope', function geolocationService($http, $q, $rootScope) {

    function geolocationPositionP (){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(                   
            function (position) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    console.log(position);
                    deferred.resolve(position);
                });
            },
            function(error){
                deferred.reject(error);
            },
            {timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 0});
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function geolocationAddressP(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var address = {};
        var geolocationPromise = geolocationPositionP();
        geolocationPromise.then(function(position){
            $http.post('/bignibou/geolocation/approximateReverse/', {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude})
            .success(function(formattedAddress){
                address.formattedAddress = formattedAddress;
                address.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                address.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                deferred.resolve(address);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                deferred.reject(data);
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        geolocationAddress : function(){
            return geolocationAddressP();
        } 
    };  
}])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a async call issue. Can you try

```
 geolocationService.geolocationPosition().then(function(data) {
     geolocationAddress = data;
});
```

**Update**: The method `geolocationPosition` needs to return promise or resource object due to async nature of code. Or you can even try callback method

```
 geolocationPosition : function(){
            var defer=$q.defer();
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    return $http.post('/bignibou/geolocation/approximateReverse/', {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude})
                    .then(function(formattedAddress){
                        var address = {};
                        address.formattedAddress = formattedAddress;
                        defer.resolve(address);
                    },
                    function(data, status, headers, config){
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(status);
                        defer.reject(status)
                    });
                }, errorFn, {
                    timeout : 10000
                });
                return defer.promise
            }
```

Read a bit about `$q` http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q

Comment: Ok i see the issue need to rewrite your method to return promise.

Comment: I see. I suspected the issue was with the fact that navigator.geolocation is called first....

Comment: Put a breakpoint at line `defer.resolve(address);` and see what address object value is